# Using Row Pivot Together

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My Raw Query Is

```
select element1_name, element1_value, element2_name, element2_value
  from reports r
```

I Want Convert element_name,element_value Rows To Columns So Write This Query

```
select *
  from (select *
          from (select element1_name,
                       element1_value,
                       element2_name,
                       element2_value
                  from reports r)
        pivot(max(element1_value) as one
           for element1_name in('C' as C, 'Si' as SI, 'P' as P)))
pivot(max(element2_value) as tow
   for element2_name in('C' as C, 'Si' as SI, 'P' as P))
```

There Is A Way That Write Two Pivot Together Without Two Sub Query  Like this 
`Select * (...) pivot element1,pivot element2`

Question:How to optimize this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
select *
from (select element1_name,
             element1_value,
             element2_name,
             element2_value
      from reports) AS R
pivot(max(element1_value) for element1_name in('C' as C, 'Si' as SI, 'P' as P)) as PV1
pivot(max(element2_value) for element2_name in('C' as C, 'Si' as SI, 'P' as P)) as PV2;
```